# directoryContentsAtPath deprecated iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am using `directoryContentsAtPath:` which  is deprecated in iOS 4 what to use instead this??

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> **[directoryContentsAtPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-CHDCIJFD)**
>
> Returns the directories and files
>   (including symbolic links) contained
>   in a given directory. (Deprecated in
>   iOS 2.0. Use
>   **contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:**
>   instead.)